# How to perform euclidean distance analysis with coefficients?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst

I would like to perform an euclidean distance analysis in ArcGIS 10 for multi-points which represent seaports. The thing is these facilities have different capabilities for handling and i want to take this specialty into consideration in my analysis. Thats why i added a column in my attribute table.

How i represent this coefficient in my analysis?

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: You would need to be more specific about what you mean by "take ... into consideration" and what the objectives of your analysis are.  Without that information it seems to me this question cannot adequately be answered.